# Can I share CSS files across multiple Netbeans Java web projects?

Tags: css, netbeans, web-applications

I'm wondering if there is a way to do this.

This may not be a Netbeans specific question but I figured my developing environment would be helpful just in case.

Comment: What's your question/problem?

Comment: "Can I share CSS files across multiple Netbeans Java web projects?"

Comment: Not to be coy: but I'm looking for an elegant way to use the same CSS file within different projects.  I could deploy a web project that JUST has the CSS file, then reference that from the other web projects, via URL, but that seems like a workaround.  I'm just looking for Netbeans to have a way to use the same file, but bundle it with all of my web projects.

Comment: You want an external style sheet. If you're talking about getting it to work locally (i.e. on your home computer, not uploaded) use either the full file path (you can get this in many ways. one is to open the local file in a web browser) or a relative path (e.g. "my-css-folder/my-css-file.css"). No offense, but http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: I don't want to have to deploy a web application in a central location, that never changes, then have each web application reference it.  It's much easier to have all of my web applications deploy with the CSS file it so that they have a local, relative, path to access it.

Comment: For example, I can create Java code in a separate project, then re-used that project in multiple other Java projects without cutting/pasting it into them.  I'd like a way to do this with a CSS file.  Whether its through some IDE-fu or packaging-fu!